# Adding nodes to term instead of terms to nodes

Tags: 6, taxonomy-terms

Is there a way to easily add nodes to terms? In other other words, let's say I have a taxonomy called top 5 sellers and I have a collection of nodes that represent books.

Currently it's hard to manage something like that because I have to search and find each book, and then assign the taxonomy term to it. I'm looking for a way to do it 'the other way around' where I have a gui that lets me choose a taxonomy and then choose nodes to add and subtract to it.

I hope that is clear. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [Views Bulk Operations](http://drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations)

Comment: Although the idea is different, this works

Answer (score 1):

I've had a look around and I'm surprised I've not been able to find what you're looking for. It seems like functionality that people would want. The best I've been able to find is [programmatically adding a node to a term](http://www.i-chaumiere.com/update-drupal-node-programmatically-add-node-taxonomy-term). I'm not sure of your experience but if you've built any modules before, it probably wouldn't be too much of a task to add a user interface to this bit of code and develop your own module to do what you want to to (and then publish it on d.o for the rest of us :))